# Get latest iOS sdk on Xcode 3.0?

Tags: ios, xcode

I recently installed Xcode 3.0 on my mac mini which can only run Leopard. Is there any way to target the latest devices and get the latest SDK for it? Thanks

Comment: No, you need to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. To use latest SDK you need latest XCode version, to install latest XCode you need OS X 10.10+